# See who changed a certificate on Windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, logging, ssl-certificate, certificate

I usually log into my server using RDC. Recently the certificate changed (got a popup while loggin in) and I don't know who changed it.  We have a self issued certificate but none of the admins changed it.

I'd like to see who (user/proccess) changed the certificate.

Is there a way to see this?

I forgot to mention that I looked into the certificate details and it says that it has been issued two days ago.

Comment: Look at the details of the cert. Does it have a recent issue date? As HopelessN00b suggests below, it could be something else that's changed.

Comment: Yes it does I forgot to mention it in the original post. It's issued two days ago (and none of the admins did this)

Answer (score 1):

1. No, not unless you have audit-level logging of file changes, which you don't.
2. It's far, far, far more likely that your server name, DNS suffix or IP address changed than your certificate did.  Certificates are cryptographically generated and tend to resist being altered.  DNS and IP addresses, on the other hand, are not.

Comment: The reason I believe the certificate is changed is because of the issue date (which is two days ago). The IP and DNS name weren't changed recently.

Comment: @iamuser That's not... just, no.  A new certificate was issued.  This is vastly different than a "changed certificate."  You need to have your admins ask this question (which isn't even a question worth asking, in all probability), as I've become convinced that you don't have the technical foundation to understand or make use of the answer to how and why a new certificate was issued (probably by an automated process, for what it's worth).

Comment: @HopeplessN00b Well I know I lack knowledge and I'm sorry for my initial bad construction of the question, but are you trying to tell me that windows servers reissue their own (self signed) certificates -automatically? (if yes, what should I look into to see when they get reissued?)